# How can I use dic in python to search values and get a key?

Tags: python

> Hi, I'm new in python. I want to do a meet in the middle attack (a
>   task for the university) Here's my situation. I have 5 files 
>   Plaintext.txt = xxxx EncText.txt = yyyy [files_description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q04l0.jpg)
>
> I want to find a pair of key considering that one string in
>   encPlain.txt have to be the same in decCipher.txt
>
> I add this values in a dictionary in python and I have this
>   *Encryption_Dictionary {'18CBA6E': 'D007603A0DAD6E41', '18CBA76': 'DC568DC3F8674D70'} Dec_Dictionary {'18CBA7B': '4D7C2E7879E0E8EA',
>   '18CBA6C': '44F58706BEC4B043'}*
>
> How can I compare the values of this two Dictionary in order to get
>   the pair of keys in case that this two string are equal? Sorry for my
>   English.This is my code for now.

```
import sys
dicKeyEnc = {}
dicKeyDec = {}
    def main():
        with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as key, 
        open(sys.argv[2],'r') as encPlain,
        open(sys.argv[3],'r') as decCipher:
            for i,j,k in zip(key,encPlain,decCipher):
                i = i.strip()
                j = j.strip()
                k = k.strip()
                dicKeyEnc[i]=j
                dicKeyDec[i]=k

        print (dicKeyEnc)
        print ("\n")
        print (dicKeyDec)
main()
```

Comment: Welcome  to SO. Please include a MCVE that is posted directly to SO.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is an iteration that will give you the list of key pairs that contain the same value. It's done as list comprehension so it's more pythonic

```
[(key1, key2) for key1, value1 in dicKeyEnc.items() for key2, value2 in dicKeyDec.items() if value1 == value2]
```